# List of out of place topics in the Talmud

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara

I was talking with a rabbi, who mentioned that once he had seen a list of discussions in the Talmud (most probably authored by [R' Eliashiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Shalom_Eliashiv)), that were in an unexpected place, and by learning only the relevant tractate of Talmud, one would easily overlook them. I could remember one such example [mentioned here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108438/15256), namely on [Arakhin 3b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Arakhin.3b.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) an important issue is discussed about *sukkot* in spite of having its own tractate. So I am looking for halakhically relevant [sugyot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemara#The_Sugya) not present in their own tractate. Have you seen this list? Or can we come up with such a list in a community wiki format?

Comment: How do you define "out of place"? Does the fact that lighting Chanukah candles is discussed in Tractate Shabbat, "a propos of kindling lights" constitute an "out of place" discussion of Chanukah? How about tefillin in Avodah Zarah?

Comment: @JoshK Chanukkah doesn't have a separate tractate, so I wouldn't consider it out of place. But you've mentioned Tractate Shabbat, so for example the need to say _Aneinu_ in _Shema koleinu_ is written there on [24a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.24a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), while I would have expected it in _Taanit._

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer, but it is useful relevant information. There is a book called Sefer Hamafteach that is an index of the entire talmud. So for example if you wanted to see all sugyot related to Sukkah, you could look up the entry and find those that aren't in the expected Masechet. There is both a hebrew and english edition.

http://hamafteach.org/

Comment: This is a compilation of wherever topics are discussed, not specifically the ones which are discussed in the wrong places.